# Chrome task manager CPU column meaning

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was testing with the Chrome task manager recently and found that one of my tabs had a CPU usage of 325.1 ...I was under the impression that this number was CPU %, but now I'm thinking it means something else.  Anyone have any idea as to what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPU - The most recent measurement of the process’s CPU usage, expressed as the percentage of a single CPU core used in total, by all of the process’s threads. This gives a value from zero to CpuInfo.numOfProcessors*100, which can exceed 100% in multi-threaded processes. Only available when receiving the object as part of a callback from onUpdated or onUpdatedWithMemory.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes/